# how to retrieve wordpress custom post type categories list in redux framework option in select dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework

i have created custom post called "Product" and "Product Categories". Now i am able to see new Product in wordpress dashboard menu ie :

- Products

  - All Products
  - Add New
  - Product Categories

Now i want to retrieve this custom type categories list in redux framework option select dropdown field.

### example code for redux option framework :

```
array(
'id'       => 'opt-select-categories-b',
'type'     => 'select',
'data'     => 'categories',
'args'      => array( 'post_types' => 'product_category', ),
'title'    => __( 'Categories Select Option', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
'subtitle' => __( 'No validation can be done on this field type', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
'desc'     => __( 'This is the description field, again good for additional info.', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
```

please help...

thanks

Comment: How did you create "Product Categories"? Are you sure it isn't a taxonomy? Probably it is a taxonomy and you will have to do a different query to retrieve this.

Comment: yes it is :

`register_taxonomy( 'product_category', 'product', $args );`

can't we retrieve like 

`'data'     => 'categories',`

Comment: try changing `'data' => 'categories'` to `'data' => 'taxonomies'`

Comment: If it didn't work try this `'data' => 'terms',
            'args' => array('taxonomies'=>'product_category', 'args'=>array()),`

Comment: `'data' => 'terms', 'args' => array('taxonomies'=>'product_category', 'args'=>array()),` is working but this one is also working `'data'     => 'categories', 'args'      => array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_category' ),`

now can you please tell me how to apply in front end to display the latest 5 post in selected custom category from redux option framework ?

Comment: Well first you will have to find a way retrieving the selected custom category. Latest 5 posts can be accomplished through `posts_per_page` and `order` i guess. I don't know the redux framework but try searching it for a bit. If you still can't find a solution, edit your question again!